# Sveltekit Dynamic Routing

Tags: sveltekit

I'm attempting to create a details page with dynamic routing. My general routes look like this:

```
src /
  routes /
    products /
      [id].svelte
      index.svelte
```

When I try to load http://localhost:3000/products/1234 I get a 404 and I'm not entirely sure why. Looking through the docs shows this should be valid.

This is the error I get:

```
Not found: /products/123

Error: Not found: /products/123
    at resolve (file:///C:/projects/sveltekit/ecommerce/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/ssr.js:1824:14)
    at async Object.handle (c:/projects/sveltekit/ecommerce/src/hooks.ts:8:14)
    at async respond (file:///C:/projects/sveltekit/ecommerce/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/ssr.js:1760:10)
    at async file:///C:/projects/sveltekit/ecommerce/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/chunks/index.js:4374:24
```

EDIT: The route /products works as expected.

Comment: Does the endpoint /products work?

Comment: Yes it does, no issues there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A silly typo is what caused all of this in my source. Nothing more. product != products for future reference.